# Android NDK-BUILD program crashes on static array allocation

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I'm new to android programming. I have a native C application that I am building with NDK-Build. I am doing a static allocation in one of the threads.

int X[64][4096]; //<-- exactly 1 MB space required.

When i run this using an adb shell, I get a "segmentation fault".  If I reduce the array to just X[63][4096], it seems to run fine. Now I know there is a 16MB or something like that limit in android for VMs, but this program hardly allocates takes up 2MB in RAM (and settings->Apps shows I have another 650 MB spare ram left).

Any idea what might be causing this crash? And how to fix it?

regards

Comment: I don't know anything about android; that being said, all the implementations of threads I know of place a tunable limit on stack size -- pthreads have pthread_attr_setstacksize(), the winapi takes the stacksize as parameter, etc. Either find how to set this parameter on android or use malloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The allocation you're doing actually isn't static. If `X` is a local variable inside a function it will be dynamically allocated on the stack (which typically is much smaller than the heap) each time the function is entered, and freed when the function returns.

If you really meant for `X` to be static (i.e. there should be one copy of `X` shared across all instances of the thread function) you could declare the variable `static`.
If you meant for each thread to have its own copy of X you should explictly allocate space on the heap using `malloc() / new []` and free it with `free() / delete []`.

Comment: The Android pthreads implementation has a 1MB default stack size, so a stack variable that large is likely to explode.  Moving it to the heap or the BSS area using the above advice should make the crash go away.

Comment: All the answers given here are good and make sense. I want to thank all of you. But there is only one answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to port a game from Linux to Android, but I'm having so much trouble with Android's tiny 1 MB stack, which is completely inadequate, and causing segfaults all over the place. On Linux the default stack size is 8 MB, and on Windows, the stack was easily configurable in VS.  Is there some way to increase the stack size on Android NDK, so I don't have to replace all my fixed arrays with slow and ugly malloc/free's?